# How to print two lines if first lines matches a pattern?

Tags: fasta

I have a long file (fasta) like this:

```
>Eha-Novel-38_5p 
ACCCATTTTCGTCTGAGGATAAT
>Eha-Novel-38_3p* 
TTTCCCAGACCCAAATGGGTGC
>Eha-Novel-46_3p 
AATGGCGGCCTGATATCCCGGA
>Eha-Novel-46_5p* 
TGGGGTATTAAGCCGCGATTGT
>Eha-Novel-44_3p 
TATCACAGTCATTTACGGGTAC
>Eha-Novel-44_5p* 
TCCCGTATTTGACTGTGACTGAG
```

I want to print only lines without the "*" and its following line.

Desired output:

```
>Eha-Novel-38_5p 
ACCCATTTTCGTCTGAGGATAAT
>Eha-Novel-46_3p 
AATGGCGGCCTGATATCCCGGA
>Eha-Novel-44_3p 
TATCACAGTCATTTACGGGTAC
```

I tried using grep "*" -v -A 1 FILE, but that did not work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added what I tried before because I agree with you. However, I understood that quite many people actually help people to write code here, no? I tried using grep "*" -v -A 1 FILE, but that did not work.

Comment: SOLVEDgrep  --no-group-separator -e "p$" FILEA -A 1